# When using AzCopy to migrate files from onprem to Azure Files are files only saved upon successful MD5 comparison?

Tags: azure, azcopy

I am migrating many files from an on-prem environment to Azure and would like to use AzCopy.

Does AzCopy automatically calculate the local file MD5 hash and submit it when uploading files?  Upon completion of a file upload using AzCopy does Azure compare the client submitted MD5 against a calculated MD5 of the file in Azure, and if so does it not save the file?  Is an error message displayed or relayed?

I've searched the documentation for AzCopy and cant get any details regarding this.  There is a "/CheckMD5" switch but its only for use when downloading files FROM an azure file container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to find in the AzCopy docs that appear to indicate AzCopy does do MD5 creation and confirmation when uploading files:

"AzCopy by default uses .NET MD5 implementation to calculate the MD5 when copying objects..."

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy#enable-fips-compliant-md5-algorithms-for-azcopy-when-you-use-fips-compliant-algorithms-for-encryption-hashing-and-signing